# strange eof flags in stream

Tags: c++

I have encountered a strange problem when parsing text file using c++ file stream. Here is the code:

```
while (true)
{       
    std::getline(inFile, line);
    if (!inFile.good())
    {
        std::cout << "Fail, bad and eof flags:" << inFile.fail() << inFile.bad() << inFile.eof() << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    parseLine(line);        
}
```

When the read terminates, the output is:

```
Fail, bad and eof flags:001
```

But actually the reader does not reach the end of file. I open the file and find that the next character is actually 26 (ASCII code). Then the problem is: 1) why the eof flag is set when reading this character, and how to avoid this kind of false termination? and 2) how to recover from this state? Thanks!

PS: thanks the replies. What if I read the file in binary mode? Any better solution? I use the Windows platform but the file seems to be an unix file.

Comment: Look at what control code 26 is.

Comment: What type of file is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why the eof flag is set when reading this character

Because it's the EOF marker character.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file):

> In **Microsoft's DOS and Windows** (and in CP/M and many DEC operating
>   systems), reading from the terminal will never produce an EOF.
>   Instead, programs recognize that the source is a terminal (or other
>   "character device") and **interpret a given reserved character or
>   sequence as an end-of-file indicator; most commonly this is an ASCII
>   Control-Z, code 26.**

---

> how to avoid this kind of false termination

It's not a "false" termination.

---

> how to recover from this state?

You don't need to.

If you were trying to read a "binary file" where arbitrary characters would be expected, you would open your file stream in binary mode.

Answer (score 2):

The ASCII character 26 is the SUB control character, which in caret notation is `^Z`. This might be recognizable to you as the Windows end of file character. So assuming ASCII and Windows, there you go.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

[Getline and 16h (26d) character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935760/getline-and-16h-26d-character)

Looks like you have to write your own *getline* function.  Seems there is no way around it :p  That I know of, and it seems no one else knows.  If anyone knows a better way, chime in.